# SUM multiple date ranges in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySql table 'Products' with three columns:

```
Date | Product | Qty
```

My aim is to SUM the qty of each product for every week.

Getting the SUM between two given dates would be easy:

```
SELECT SUM(qty) FROM products WHERE date >= '2010-01-01' AND date < '2011-01-1'
```

I can generate a list of weeks in Php using something like:

```
$today = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last week Monday'));
$future = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+90 days'));

$period = new DatePeriod(
 new DateTime($today),
 new DateInterval('P7D'),
 new DateTime($future)
);
foreach ($period as $key => $value) {
    $dates .= $value->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

Is there a MySql query that would work to Group By and SUM by dates? Or would I be better off looping through in Php?

Comment: if i recall correctly, there is a mysql function for it `week()`, then you could use it in conjunction with group by

Comment: Not need to use php script to find a week. you can use week function in mysql and sum of qty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can use [`Year()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) and [`Week()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) functions in MySQL, to get the year and week number for a given date. `Week()` function will return week number from 0 to 53. So, you will be needed to use `Year()` function alongwith, if you have data spanning over multiple years.
- But then, you will be **more interested** in knowing the start date and end date for the concerned week. This is where we can use a very interesting function [`DayOfWeek()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek). It returns the weekday index for a given date (*1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, …, 7 = Saturday*)
- We can use [`Date_Add()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function using the weekday index value and the actual date value, to determine the starting week date and ending week date for a given date.

Try the following (**if the Week starts on Sunday**) :

```
SELECT 
  DATE_ADD(`date`, INTERVAL(1 - DAYOFWEEK(`date`)) DAY) AS week_start_date, 
  DATE_ADD(`date`, INTERVAL(7 - DAYOFWEEK(`date`)) DAY) AS week_end_date, 
  SUM(qty) 
FROM 
  products 
GROUP BY week_start_date, week_end_date
```

---

If the week starts on Monday, another handy function is [`WeekDay()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday). It returns the weekday index for date (*0 = Monday, 1 = Tuesday, … 6 = Sunday*).

Try the following (**if the Week starts on Monday**) :

```
SELECT 
  DATE_ADD(`date`, INTERVAL(0 - WEEKDAY(`date`)) DAY) AS week_start_date, 
  DATE_ADD(`date`, INTERVAL(6 - WEEKDAY(`date`)) DAY) AS week_end_date, 
  SUM(qty) 
FROM 
  products 
GROUP BY week_start_date, week_end_date
```

Comment: Fantastic answer - I had no idea about those Sql functions!

Comment: Just realised, there's only one issue:

Your command returns only the weeks where there's data in the table. I'm trying to use this to return data that displays the quantity for every week, even if the quantity is zero.

For example:

    week1: 0
   week2: 200
   week3: 0

And so on.. Possible?

Comment: @charliechina To get all the weeks, we will have to use another table which contains all the week dates. It is doable. Will give an updated answer in some time.

Comment: @charliechina what would be the starting week ? Without a definition of minimum week number, this query can become as cumbersome as it can get.

Comment: start date would be today and end date today +90. Or defined by Php variable. 
One way I thought about would be to make a temp table with all the dates and do a Join but this feels like a bit of a hack!

Comment: @charliechina that is the only way - either create a temp table or in your query, use a custom Derived table. For eg: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469901/mysql-week-get-all-weeks-in-date-range-with-without-records

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with a group by like

```
GROUP BY week(date)
```

Answer (score 1):

GROUP BY so do

```
SELECT SUM(qty) FROM products GROUP BY WEEK(date);
```