# Get next date based on the day number - mysql

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql and I want to write a query where I pass in the day number and it gives me the next date in the coming/current week.

Examples :

1. If today is Monday (01-Jan-2018) and I pass in 5, then I want Friday (05-Jan-2018).
2. If today is Friday (05-Jan-2018) and I pass in 1, then I want Monday (08-Jan-2018).

I have written a basic query but I am not able to make it generic.

Query :

```
select date_add(now(), interval dayofweek(now()) + (6 - @day_num)  day);
```

Comment: Can you precise your question?  The number is the weekday?

Comment: yes it'll be day of the week. between 1 and 7.

Comment: If today is day 2 of a week, and I pass day 2, do you want today or next week day 2?

Comment: I am assuming that 1st day of week in your case is Monday, and not Sunday.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya yes its Monday.

Comment: @DanielBlais I want next weekday.

Comment: Is this is what you want? `select date_add(now(), interval 7 - dayofweek(now()) + @day_num day);`

Comment: `select date_add(now(), interval 7 - dayofweek(now()) + 5 day);` this is giving me `2018-11-15 13:00:37` not `2018-11-08 13:00:37`.

Comment: @Rohit if you are only going to do use this for Display purposes, then you can look at Carbon library in PHP/Laravel. Getting it done in MySQL will be lot of code with conditional expressions

Comment: no its not for only display. I'll be used to calculate next delivery date. I was able to do this with just one line in SQL but in mysql I don't konw how should I write it. SQL Query - `select DATEADD(DAY, (DATEDIFF(DAY, @day_id - 1, GETDATE()) / 7) * 7 + 7, @day_id - 1) `

Comment: check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52780138/2469308 This may give u some hints

Comment: What would happen if let's say, today is Monday (1-Jan-2018), and you enter 1. Will this give current date only, or next monday (8-Jan-2018) ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya It will be next Monday (8th)

Comment: `select date_add(now(), interval  CASE WHEN dayofweek(now()) < 5 THEN 7 - 5 + 1 ELSE 7 - dayofweek(now()) + 5 END day);`

Comment: @Rohit can you check if the posted answer works or not. Let me know the issues. It can be optimized further and I will add explanation once you confirm it it is working.If some edge cases are missed, let me know as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try (it can be optimized further, but first can you check if it works):

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) + 1 >= @day_num
       THEN (CURDATE() + INTERVAL (6 - WEEKDAY(CURDATE())) DAY) + INTERVAL @day_num DAY
       ELSE (CURDATE() + INTERVAL (0 - WEEKDAY(CURDATE())) DAY) + INTERVAL (@day_num-1) DAY
  END AS next_date;
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems to be working. only except for current day e.g. for 2 it is returning today's date not next date.

Comment: @Rohit so you are entering 2 as day_num ?

Comment: Yes. `set @day_num = 2;
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) + 1 >= @day_num
       THEN (CURDATE() + INTERVAL (6 - WEEKDAY(CURDATE())) DAY) + INTERVAL @day_num DAY
       ELSE (CURDATE() + INTERVAL (0 - WEEKDAY(CURDATE())) DAY) + INTERVAL (@day_num-1) DAY
  END AS next_date;`

Comment: @Rohit I ran the above query on my system. I am getting `2018-11-13`. Query is absolutely right. Please check carefully. Thanks.

Comment: the current day issue was due to the server's datetime. I figured it out this morning.. thanks for the help on this. Cheers!